# GeoServer 2.7.6 not displaying TIFF correctly

Tags: geoserver, wms, geotiff-tiff

I would like to upload TIFF and display it as WMS layer. But after creating layer process, WMS layer is malformed. Please be lenient, I'm fresh in GeoServer. Maybe I did something wrong that I dont understand. Here is TIFF that I want to display as WMS:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6dpoyvk372utjfd/Keihaskoski_dem_EDGE.tif?dl=0

WMS layer settings: [image]

second:
[image]

third:

[image]

fourth:
[image]

malformed WMS:

[image]

Comment: Second image shows WCS not WMS

Comment: @nmtoken My mistake, sorry. I forgot to mention that I uploaded another TIFF and it looked very well. So I suppose there is something wrong with that raster but Im not sure at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, GeoServer is displaying your tiff just fine, that is actually what it looks like with no enhancement.

If you add a normalization

```
<ContrastEnhancement>
    <Normalize/>
</ContrastEnhancement>
```

to it you get:

[image]

or with a histogram stretch:

```
<ContrastEnhancement>
    <Histogram/>
</ContrastEnhancement>
```

[image]

There is more discussion of [Contrast Enhancements](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/reference/rastersymbolizer.html#contrastenhancement) in the [raster symbolizer documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/reference/rastersymbolizer.html).

Also, 2.7.6 is pretty old you should upgrade to the 2.12.x release.

**Update**

Here is the full SLD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" 
                       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
                       xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
                       xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
                       xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
                       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <!-- a Named Layer is the basic building block of an SLD document -->
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>default_raster</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <!-- Styles can have names, titles and abstracts -->
      <Title>Default Raster</Title>
      <Abstract>A sample style that draws a raster, good for displaying imagery</Abstract>
      <!-- FeatureTypeStyles describe how to render different features -->
      <!-- A FeatureTypeStyle for rendering rasters -->
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <Name>rule1</Name>
          <Title>Opaque Raster</Title>
          <Abstract>A raster with 100% opacity</Abstract>
          <RasterSymbolizer>
            <Opacity>1.0</Opacity>
            <ContrastEnhancement>
              <Histogram/>
            </ContrastEnhancement>
          </RasterSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: Hmm now raster looks good between 1 to 34k, otherwise I see black rectangle.  Which geoserver version are you using? Could you share your layer settings?

Comment: I imported your tiff with all defaults, there are very high values at the edges of the image which dominate the view.

Comment: I'm using 2.12.1

Comment: Hmm is there a posibility to fix that? Anyway your solution helped me a lot.